# How to test material design event listener using enzyme, jest and react

Tags: reactjs, material-design, jestjs

I am testing calling of mock function (onAccept), that should be executed on <kbd>Accept</kbd> button click (the one with the class name `mdc-dialog__footer__button--accept`). I tried everything I know, but with no luck. This is all working perfectly normal in (non-testing) development environment.

I am always getting the following error:

> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
>       Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

This is my Dialog.tsx component that wrapps material Dialog:

```
import { MDCDialog } from '@material/dialog';
import * as React from 'react';
import { RefObject } from 'react';

import { IDialogProps } from '.';

export class Dialog extends React.Component<IDialogProps, any> {
    private dialogRef: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
    private dialog: MDCDialog;

    public componentWillMount() {
        const elementRef = this.props.elementRef;
        this.dialogRef = elementRef ? elementRef : React.createRef();
    }

    public render() {
        const {
            elementRef,
            className,
            children,
            role,
            isVisible,
            onClose,
            onAccept,
            onCancel,
            ...other
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <aside
                ref={ this.dialogRef }
                className={ this.getClassName() }
                role="alertdialog"
                { ...other }
            >
                <div className="mdc-dialog__surface">
                    { ...children }
                </div>
                <div className="mdc-dialog__backdrop"></div>
            </aside>

        );
    }

    public componentDidMount() {
        const {
            onAccept,
            onCancel,
            onClose,
            isVisible
        } = this.props;
        this.dialog = new MDCDialog(this.dialogRef.current);

        if (onAccept) {
            this.dialog.listen("MDCDialog:accept", onAccept);
        }

        if (onCancel) {
            this.dialog.listen("MDCDialog:cancel", onCancel);
        }

        if (onClose) {
            this.dialog.listen("MDCDialog:accept", onClose);
            this.dialog.listen("MDCDialog:cancel", onClose);
        }

        if (isVisible) {
            this.dialog.show();
        }
    }

    public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: IDialogProps) {
        if (prevProps.isVisible !== this.props.isVisible) {
            this.toggleVisibility();
        }
    }

    private toggleVisibility = () => {
        const isVisible = this.props.isVisible;
        isVisible ? this.dialog.show() : this.dialog.close();
    }

    private getClassName = (): string => {
        const {
            className
        } = this.props;

        let result = "mdc-dialog";
        result += className ? ` ${className}` : "";

        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is my test:

```
test("should execute onAccept on 'accept' button of dialog click", () => {

const onAccept = jest.fn();
const component = (
    <Dialog onAccept={ onAccept } isVisible>
        <button id="cancelButton" className="mdc-dialog__footer__button--cancel">Cancel</button>
        <button id="acceptButton" className="mdc-dialog__footer__button--accept">Accept</button>
    </Dialog>
);

const wrapper = mount(component);
wrapper.find("#acceptButton").at(0).simulate("click");

    expect(onAccept).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The important fact is that `MDCDialog.listen("MDCDialog:accept", onAccept)` puts "MDCDialog:accept" custom event on `<aside>` element. So, the question is, is there any way of testing calling of the mocked function, or at least checking that custom event has been attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of researching, I couldn't find the answer. But, at the end, I did it by attaching the component to the document body using `ReactDOM.render()`. It may not be the best solution, but it seems to work. Here is the solution:

```
test("should execute onAccept on accept button of dialog click", () => {
const onAccept = jest.fn();
const component = (
    <Dialog onAccept={ onAccept } isVisible>
        <button id="cancelButton" className="mdc-dialog__footer__button--cancel">Cancel</button>
        <button id="acceptButton" className="mdc-dialog__footer__button--accept">Accept</button>
    </Dialog>
);

ReactDOM.render(component, document.body);
const el = document.getElementById("acceptButton");
el.click();

    expect(onAccept).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I am still not sure why the previous example didn't work.